# How update pygobject without breaking any dependency?

Tags: python3, pygi

I want update the Pygobject of my system from the official repository.

The last version on official repository is **3.16.1**, but in the official package for Ubuntu is **3.12.0**.

I tried uninstall this package,but several programs would be removed(Including Software Center).

I'm new to Ubuntu, and i need at least Pygobject version **3.14**, that was the version i used on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pygobject version 3.14 is available in the official packages for Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn.

To upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) to Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic):

1. Run the update-manager application from the Unity Dash or a command line
2. In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.
3. Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.
   Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
   Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
4. In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.
5. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
6. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
7. Click Upgrade.
8. Follow the on-screen instructions.

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UtopicUpgrades

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...